# auth_user in pgAdmin

Tags: django, authentication, pgadmin

i was recently trying to test some sort of project working both on Django and pgAdmin for managing database. I created the superuser just for testing and then add some data into the database then i opened the auth_user file and this is what appeared to me:

1.First row was dedicated to me as a super user with te username and password i chose back when i created a superuser

2.Second row was someone else!!! username = myusername First_name= Tyron Last_name = Citizen and it's an active user

iI don't have a clue i didn't create such a user this was only for testing if anyone knows something about this please share with us :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you added the user during testing, so you need to check your code for any user-related operations that you could have performed. Also remember that the Django auth_user file stores both the superuser and the regular user accounts

Comment: I still didn't know the reason but I just deleted the created account.. and I moved on! but many thanks for your reply.